# Bootstrap select picker showing :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_menu' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap selectpicker but whenever I click on drop down list it is showing some error and I am unable to perform data-live search,even I have changed bootstrap version but didn't work for me

Links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url('assets/') ?>app-assets/css/bootstrap.css">    // Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/selectpicker/bootstrap-select.min.css"> // Bootstrap-select v1.13.12
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/') ?>app-assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    // jQuery v3.3.1
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/selectpicker/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>  // Bootstrap-select v1.13.12
        
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/') ?>app-assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5
```

Dropdown list with data-live search

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-hide-disabled="true" name="user" id="user">
                                    <option value=''>option 1</option>
                                    <option value=''>option 2</option>
                                    <option value=''>option 3</option>
                                    <option value=''>option 4</option>
                                    <option value=''>option 4</option>
                                    
                               
          </select>
```

Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_menu' of undefined in bootstrap-select.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the CDN links instead for Bootstrap. They work perfectly!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select
            class="selectpicker"
            data-live-search="true"
            data-hide-disabled="true"
            name="user"
            id="user"
        >
            <option value="">option 1</option>
            <option value="">option 2</option>
            <option value="">option 3</option>
            <option value="">option 4</option>
        </select>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used cdn links which is mentioned by you but  now it is showing different error and boostrap css not working now

Comment: There are no errors on my side. What error are you getting? That might be something else in your code that's affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

try this links with the same html

```
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```